# concatenate bits C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, systemc

I am looking for an elegant C++ using SystemC to concatenate bits.

A System Verilog example in one nice line:

```
bool my_variable;
uint bits_combination = {8'b0, {8{my_variable}}, 8'b1, 4'b0, 2'b1, 2'b0};
```

My best solution for C++:

```
bool my_variable;
sc_uint<32> bits_combination;
bits_combination.range(31,24) = 0;
bits_combination.range(23,16) = my_variable ? (1 << 8)-1  : 0;
bits_combination.range(15,8)  = (1 << 8)-1;
bits_combination.range(7,4)   = 0;
bits_combination.range(3,2)   = (1 << 2)-1;
bits_combination.range(1,0)   = 0;
```

Improving this line to a non ternary operator will also help:

```
my_variable ? (1 << 8)-1  : 0
```

Comment: Are the rest of the bits constant? The uint in the system verilog example has 34 bits? If the rest doesn't change have it as a mask and or in (255 << 16) if my variable is true?

Answer (score 3):

In SystemC comma operator is overloaded for concatenation. But there is no replication operator like {8{my_variable}}.

But, you can write a function that will do replication. For example:

```
template <int N, int M>
sc_uint<N*M> replicate( sc_uint<M> val) {
    sc_uint<N*M> res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        res = (res << M) | val;
    return res;
};
```

So SystemC version of your SystemVerilog sample can look like:

```
sc_uint<1> my_variable = 1;
sc_uint<32> bits_concatenation = (sc_uint<8>(0), replicate<8>(my_variable), sc_uint<8>(1), sc_uint<4>(0), sc_uint<2>(1), sc_uint<4>(0) );
```

Comment: Is there a way to cast sc_lv to sc_uint ?
If so we don't need the replicate function.

Comment: I don't quite understood sc_lv idea. Can you please elaborate it in details?  In general I think it is possible to write templated replication function that will support various datatypes.

Comment: sc_lv is an Arbitrary Width Logic Type
this is sc_lv documentation http://www.lysium.de/docs/systemc-2.2/docs/html/classsc__dt_1_1sc__lv.html it has a c'tor to initialize all bits to the same value: template<int W>
sc_dt::sc_lv< W >::sc_lv ( bool  init_value  )

Comment: Yes, but what if you want to replicate some pattern? Like replicate 010 3 times to get 010010010?

Comment: Also I can recommend AC types https://www.mentor.com/hls-lp/downloads/ac-datatypes for arbitrary width integers, fixed and floats.

Comment: Your solution is more general, I don't need to replicate patterns just a single bit.

BTW in your solution you need to use your template function _replicate_ for sc_uint<8>(1) and sc_uint<2>(1) as well. otherwise you'll have 00000001 and 01 instead of 11111111 and 11

Answer (score 2):

Looks like

```
  0b0000'0000'0000'0000'1111'1111'0000'1100 | 
( 0b0000'0000'1111'1111'0000'0000'0000'0000 * myVariable )
```